# Change jvectormap negative value color

Tags: css, svg, jvectormap

By default, when I have negative values in my jvectormap, it colors the country black (I see the following "fill" value when inspecting the country element: #000NaN). I would like to change this color. How can I do this?

Edit: It's hackish, but I updated the color of the countries when it was black by looping the countries and checking for black. Code below:

```
        try {
            map = elVectorMap.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            map.series.regions[0].setValues(data);
        } catch (e) {
            var vectorMapOptions = {
                map: 'world_mill_en',
                backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                regionStyle: {
                    initial: {
                        fill: '#aac5e1'
                    }
                },
                series: {
                    regions: [{
                        values: data,
                        scale: ['#aac5e1', '#0e569f'],
                        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                    }]
                }
            };
            elVectorMap.vectorMap(vectorMapOptions);
        }

        // Change the color of negative value countries from black to red
        elVectorMap.find('.jvectormap-element[fill="#000NaN"]').each(function(){
            $(this).css('fill', '#ffcfcd');
        });
```

Comment: Justin, please add a reproducible code example to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use this normalization function instead of the "polinomial" or "linear" values

```
normalizeFunction: function(value) {
   if (value < 0)
      return - Math.pow(Math.abs(value), 0.2)
   return Math.pow(value, 0.2);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'`. You have to change it with `normalizeFunction: 'lineal'`. However, if polynomial normalization is important to you, you can always generate two series, one with negative values and another one with positive ones to get rid somehow from the black country problem.

**Example:**

```
    series: {
      regions: [{
        values: countryData2,
        scale: ['#d6655c', '#de837c', '#e6a29d', '#eec1bd', '#f6e0de'],
        normalizeFunction: 'lineal',
        legend: {
            vertical: false,
            title: "<span style=\"font-size:7px;\">% Dif.</span>"
        }
      },
      {
        values: countryData3,
        scale: ['#e6efe6', '#b5d0b4', '#84b183', '#539152', '#227220', '#0a6308'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        legend: {
            vertical: false,
            title: "<span style=\"font-size:7px;\">% Dif.</span>"
        }
      }

      ]
    },
```

This, however, also generates 2 different Legends, but for me is not a problem at all.